# Save a file in SQL Server 2008 database with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, filestream

How can I save a file in SQL Server 2008 database with Entity Framework?

I want to use FileStream in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't work - `filestream` columns are just exposed as `varbinary(MAX)` so you should be able to set the column using Entity Framework:

Sample from [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/05/12/ado-net-entity-framework-support-filestream.aspx):

```
Files newFile = new Files();
newFile.FileID = Guid.NewGuid();
newFile.FileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("TextFile1.txt");
ctx.AddObject("Files", newFile);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But this will allocate the whole file in memory, right? Is there any other reasonable way? After all, that's the whole purpose of FILE*STREAM*.

Comment: good point Simon - the column will be treated just like any other `varbinary(MAX)` column, so this approach while it *works*, won't be very efficient or even usable for very large files.

Comment: What I do to bypass that performance limitation is store the files in the azure blob storage then save a reference to the blob in the database.

Answer (score 5):

Entity framework doesn't have support for SQL server specific features like filestream. You can't do it with EF you must fall back to ADO.NET.

Edit:

Undeleting my answer because I just tested how EF handles `FILESTREAM` columns. EF indeed works with `FILESTREAM` column so my answer is not fully correct and @BrokenGlass provided the solution. The problem is that EF ignores `FILESTREAM` keyword and doesn't really use streaming when working with `FILESTREAM` column. That column is handled as any other binary column.