# Streaming of Files from DB using Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework

We have a scenario in our project that requires us to store large files into DB. We are using entity framework 5.0 for data access.

One more thing to note here is that our project needs support for both Oracle/SQL Server.

is streaming for reading/writing possible in this scenario using entity framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370351/save-a-file-in-sql-server-2008-database-with-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks soadyp... is it still hold true with EF 5.0 or EF 6.x alphas?

Comment: im interested in that myself... have put a watch on this